# (SHINY R) I need to change column select from slider to select box with column names

Tags: r, shiny

I have a small problem. I made a program where you upload a file and have two tabs:

- First tab (table) shows all columns from files.
- Second tab (table2)  shows column selected via slider

`server.R`:

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
    data <- reactive({
        file1 <- input$file
        if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
        read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header )
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(data())){return ()}
        data()    
    })

    output$table2 <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(data())){return ()}
        data()[c(input$slider1)]    
    })

    output$tb <- renderUI({
        if(is.null(data()))
            h5("Wgraj Plik jeśli chcesz cokolwiek zrobić")
        else
            tabsetPanel(tabPanel("dane", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("wybrana kolumna", tableOutput("table2")))
    })
})
```

`ui.R`:

```
# ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Aplikacja testowa numer 5 Praca z plikiem"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file", label = h3("Wgraj Plik")),
            checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wers to etykiety', value = FALSE),
            radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Co jest separatorem', choices = c(Przecinek=',',Średnik=';',Tabulator='\t', Spacja=''), selected = ','),
            sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider"), min = 1, max = 20, value = 1)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("tb")
        )
    )
))
```

I need to change the slider into an input box with options read from column labels of uploaded file.

I tried to do something by myself via `renderUI`, but I don't know how to make it read labels of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be working for you?

First render an empty `checkboxGroupInput` and update its choices as soon as data is submitted.

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Aplikacja testowa numer 5 Praca z plikiem"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label = h3("Wgraj Plik")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wers to etykiety', value = FALSE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Co jest separatorem', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Średnik"=';',"Tabulator"='\t', "Spacja"=''), selected = ','),

      checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h3("Column names"), choices = NULL)
    ),

    mainPanel(
       uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header )
    # Change made here: use the dataSet to modify selection choices.
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))

    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()    
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable({

    # Changes made here: 1) If no box is ticked, don't try to render.
    # 2) Take list of colnames to select columns. (Multiple work.) 
    if(is.null(data()) || is.null(input$choices1)){return ()}
    data()[input$choices1]    
  })

  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Wgraj Plik jeśli chcesz cokolwiek zrobić")
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("dane", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("wybrana kolumna", tableOutput("table2")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```